# What's the maximum height mobs can fall from without dying?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The question stands for itself. I'm especially interested in skeletons, but I like to keep the topic general.

I something to get skeletons from a monster spawner go up and fall, but they still need a few hits to die, so I would like to know how high I need to let them fall so that they would only need one more hit.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the mob? Different health, etc?

Comment: It depends on the health of the mob.

Comment: I knew it depends on the health, I was expecting a general answer like @OrigamiRobot's

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Fall damage](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Health_and_damage#Fall_damage) is calculated by the following formula:

> Fall Damage = number of blocks - 3

1 damage is half a heart. (As is 1 health)

Using this formula and a list of [Mob Healths](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Health#Health), you can figure out the maximum height from which each mob can fall while staying alive. **Simply subtract 1 from a mob's health and add 3!**

For example, a Skeleton has 10 hearts (20 health).  This means it can take 19 damage without dying.  Using the fall damage formula, we can see that the maximum height a Skeleton can fall from without dying is 22.

An Enderman, on the other hand, has 20 hearts (40 health).  That means an Enderman can survive a 42 block fall!

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that some mobs don't deal fall damage, like chickens, ghasts, snow golems, blazes, magma cubes, iron golems, ocelots, bats, the ender dragon and wither (copied from the Minecraft Wiki)

Comment: And skeletons and zombies sometimes wear armor which reduces fall damage.

Comment: Or, y'know, just add 2.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum height, as I remember it, is 22 blocks for a skeleton. This should leave them with 1/2 a heart left, so that they can be killed by a single punch.

Comment: note that endermen survive from higher, and mod mobs can go all ways, (up to immune from fall damage)

Comment: This is a good general answer though. If you expanded it to cover all (vanilla) mobs and their heights, it would be even better.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie far from a minecraft super expert, I honestly didnt know it was different for different mobs. I was going to edit in the rest of them once I read your comment, however it seems Origami has beat me to it. Curses!

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula - Number of mobs health altogether (Half a heart) -1 +3 then you will get how many blocks it can fall with half a heart left! This is a easy tip to make your own mob grinder!

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of the formula - wouldn't -1 +3 give you +2?